# Elasticsearch search for attributes matching query over multiple documents

Tags: elasticsearch

I have data modeled where multiple documents with different attributes are logically connected over a chainID because the documents are indexed with an undefined amount of time between them i.e. after they're executed in the backend. All documents are indexed on the same index. Example documents:

```
Doc 1:
   {
     "att1": "a",
     "att2": "b",
     "chainID": "123"
   }
Doc 2:
   {
     "att3": "c",
     "att4": "d",
     "chainID": "123"
   }
Doc 3:
   {
     "att1": "x",
     "att2": "y",
     "chainID": "678"
   }
Doc 4:
   {
     "att3": "z",
     "att4": "u",
     "chainID": "678"
   }
```

Mapping:

```
{
    "properties": {
        "att1": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
                "keyword": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "ignore_above": 256
                }
            }
        },
        "att2": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
                "keyword": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "ignore_above": 256
                }
            }
        },
        "att3": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
                "keyword": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "ignore_above": 256
                }
            }
        },
        "att4": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
                "keyword": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "ignore_above": 256
                }
            }
        },
        "chainID": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
                "keyword": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "ignore_above": 256
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I want to group the documents by chainID and search through the aggregated results so that a query with `att1=a AND att3=c` would have `chainID=123` as a result.

I tried the following query which resulted in no matching documents

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "term": {
                        "att1.keyword": "a"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "term": {
                        "att3.keyword": "c"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "aggs": {
        "chainIDs": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "chainID.keyword"
            },
            "aggs": {
                "docs": {
                    "top_hits": {
                        "_source": [
                            "chainID"
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It seems like the aggregation happens after the query is processed. What I would like to do is aggregate the documents per their chainID and run the query against the aggregated documents. Is this possible with elasticsearch or do I need to adjust my mappings/data model?

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing "must" with should (logic OR). "Must" requires the same document to have att1=1 and att3=c (logic AND).

```
{
"query": {
    "bool": {
        "should": [
            {
                "term": {
                    "att1.keyword": "a"
                }
            },
            {
                "term": {
                    "att3.keyword": "c"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
},
"aggs": {
    "chainIDs": {
        "terms": {
            "field": "chainID.keyword"
        },
        "aggs": {
            "docs": {
                "top_hits": {
                    "_source": [
                        "chainID"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Sadly that doesn't work since my query requires both att1=a and att3=c to be true in the context of grouped by chainID Documents. The attributes can be split over multiple documents which are connected with the chainID. So in my example `doc1 would match att1 = a` and `doc2 would match att3=c` which should result in documents with the `chainID 123` being returned since both have the same chainID and  together satisfy the query.

Comment: the examples of documents that you showed do not have any documents att1=a AND att3=c so there are no results for your query and as a result your aggregation is empty.

I don't know if in your base there are att1=a AND att3=c in the same document but from what you reported it doesn't exist.

Comment: if you want to filter docs 1 and 2 you would have to do something like this:
(att1=a AND att2=b) OR (att3=c AND att4=d)

Comment: yeah my wording is a bit unclear. What I want to do is to query groups by their respective chainID. That would mean doc 1 and 2 combined, and doc 3 and 4 combined since they share a chainID. The result of these groups is what my query should be sent against. So in my example group chainID 123 contains att1=a , att2=b, att3=c and att4=d. And this group would match the query att1=a and att3=c. Hope this is clearer